# I'm using OJS 3.3.0.7, Custom Block Manager not showing

Tags: ojs

I'm trying to show a menu on the right side of the web using custom block manager, but after I added the item it doesn't show, I've been searching and it said that the cause of the error was the version of the OJS itself which is OJS 3.1.1.4 but I'm already using OJS 3.3.0.7. found a way to fix it but I don't have the access for the cpanel. Is there any other way around to fix the problem?

I've tried disable and enable the plugin and the result still the same.